A movie about tiny aliens
I ran across some scenes from a movie in 1993, which mean it can't be made later than that. In that movie, there are two characters that are tiny humans, about the size of a doll, both men, and travel in something that looks like flying saucer or airplane that fit for one person. I presume they were aliens. One man dressed in a trenchcoat, carried a long handgun, about the size of the 475 Magnum. The other guy dressed in some weird outfit, somehow resembling Khan in the original "Star Trek". The second guy was cocky and told a full-sized human that he must take his order, and the human smashed both the guy and his plane with his fist. Then I left for a while, and when I came back, the first alien was shooting a human; his gun was too small but he managed to kill that human by shooting many times at one single spot. I do not know if that was their natural size, or if they had been shrunk down.
I am really, really hopeful that before I die (not that I am dying), I would be able to learn the name of that movie. Please help. Oh, and it looks like it is an American movie. The alien in trenchcoat seemed to be the protagonist. It looks like something from the 80's, no graphic effect.

Sounds faintly familiar. Are you sure it wasn't one of those killer doll movies, like the Puppet Master films?

No, they are humans, not dolls. The trenchcoat guy seemed to be the hero of the movie.

And your intuition nearly hits the nail on its head, Walt. The movie does have something to do with Puppet Master.

Kind of, yeah. I also realized there was a similar question once; I'll mark it.

Small trench coated human with long-barrelled pistol makes me think of Tim Thomerson in Dollman, (1991).

Brick Bardo (Tim Thomerson) is a traveller from outer space who is
  forced to land on Earth. Though regular sized on his home planet, he
  is doll-sized here on Earth, as are the enemy forces who have landed
  as well. While Brick enlists the help of an impoverished girl and her
  son, the bad guys enlist the help of a local gang.


Oh, right. Full Moon. Maybe the crossover?

Dollman it is. You guys are great! All those years and I never associated the size with the word "doll", but interestingly, it came out of nowhere when I wrote the description.
